# Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on array

Tags: php, pdo

Ambiente:
php 7.4.4 e Apache24 em um Microsoft Server R2 2012.
@EDIT: Banco de Dados MS Sql Server.

Pessoal estou recebendo o seguinte **erro**:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on array in C:\Apache24\htdocs\teste\backend\dist\fx.php:564 Stack trace: #0 C:\Apache24\htdocs\teste\backend\dist\conn.php(52): selectSQL('VW_FATOVENDA', Array, 'WHERE 1 = 1 AND...', Array, Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\Apache24\htdocs\cns_metronic\backend\dist\fx.php on line 564
```

Acessando a linha informada, tenho a seguinte função:

```
function selectSQL($table, $columns, $where, $parameters, $pdo){

  $querySQL = "SELECT ".implode(", ", $columns)." FROM ".$table." ".$where." ";

  $query = $pdo->prepare($querySQL);

  if(is_array($parameters) && count($parameters) > 0){
    foreach ($parameters as $key => $value) {
      $query->bindValue(($key + 1), $value);
    }
  }
  $query->execute();
  $returnValues = $query->fetchAll();

  return $returnValues;
}
```

@EDIT:

Informando também a query que é montada.

```
$table = 'VW_FATOVENDA';
$columns = array('Vendedor', 'DataFaturamento', 'SUM(Subtotal) as Subtotal');
$where = "WHERE 1 = 1 AND CONVERT(DATE, DataFaturamento, 103) BETWEEN CONVERT(DATE, '01/12/2019', 103) AND CONVERT(DATE, '10/12/2019', 103)  AND TipoMovimento IN ('VENDA', 'NOTA MÃE')
    GROUP BY Vendedor, DataFaturamento, Dia, Ano
    ORDER BY dia ASC";
$parameters = array();
$pdo = array();

$graficoSQL = selectSQL($table, $columns, $where, $parameters, $pdo);
```

Lembrando que os parâmetros de conexão são esses:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

$host_bd = 'localhost';
$username_bd = 'root';
$password_bd = 'root123';
$nome_bd = 'Base_Testes';

try{
  $pdo = new PDO('sqlsrv:Server='.$host_bd.';Database='.$nome_bd, $username_bd, $password_bd);
  $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

}catch(PDOException $e){
  //finalDialogue(2, "Erro no acesso ao banco de dados.", null);
  echo 'Erro no acesso ao banco de dados:<br />' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Procurei diversas formas de tentar resolver esse problema mas sempre caio na mesma mensagem de erro, também já revisei as **extensions** e todas estão na pasta "ext" devidamente inicializadas sem qualquer tipo de erro.
Detalhe, em computador local funcionou mas no servidor não funciona.

Comment: Lógico que vai dar esse erro, você declara `$pdo = array();`  e em seguida `$graficoSQL = selectSQL($table, $columns, $where, $parameters, $pdo);`

Comment: Obrigado pela observação tiozão!

Comment: Obrigado nada! São R$50,00 pela informação e mais R$50,00 por me chamar de tiozão sem autorização.